# Installation help

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu, and now have a Ubuntu folder in "Programs" on my C drive. It has an install icon in the foldeer, but it doesn't do anything. What do I do next to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Next time try researching your answer - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+install+ubuntu&oq=how+to+install+ubuntu is not difficult to do. This site is for questions that need an advanced, personalised answer - I know for a fact that there are many installation tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it on a thumb drive. Get the program that will put the ios image on your thumb drive, have your computer open in bios, then have it boot from the usb before booting from the c drive or anything else